# How to check if any string from a list of strings is a substring of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the below code:

```
fruits = ['apple','orange','mango']

description = 'A mango is an edible stone fruit produced by the tropical tree Mangifera indica'.
```

I need to check if the description string contains any word from the fruits list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) along with  `in`:

```
>>> fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
>>> description = 'A mango is an edible stone fruit produced by the tropical tree Mangifera indica'
>>> any(f in description for f in fruits)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility (in case you find the `fruit in description` syntax confusing) would be to use the `__contains__` method, like that:

```py
any(description.__contains__(fruit) for fruit in fruits)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list of all the words in the string by splitting it at every " " char. And then check if this list contians the searched words.

```
fruits = ['apple','orange','mango']
description = 'A mango is an edible stone fruit produced by the tropical tree Mangifera indica'
words = description.split(" ")
for searched in fruits:
   if searched  in words:
      print(f"{searched} found")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check this like that:

```
a=[True if fruit in description else False for fruit in fruits]
```

And the output will be:

```
[False, False, True]
```